# sorting and paging on web part

Tags: sorting, web-part, paging, data-view-web-part

sorting in dataviewwebpart only sorting within display items. Paging is enabled to display 10 items per page. Also, How do I put 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, (next, previous) for the paging?

They give you dataview wp but looks like it's also limited. I wish it had more capabilities like gridview. Anyone????

Answer (score 2):

You need to customise the DVWP within SharePoint Designer. In this, you can enable sorting for columns as well as enabling pagination.

further enhancements require you to edit the underlying XSLT behind the web part, which you can also do in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Sorting is working but limiting to the display items. So, it sorts within the first 10 items that displayed on the current page.

Paging is working (like this < 1-10 >). But I like to put 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: Oh, I did all that with SP Designer.